# Selecting multiple divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a HTML structure how this:

```
<div class="className"></div>
<div class="className"></div>
...
<div class="className"></div>
```

I am trying to select these elements with jQuery. For that, I'd like to know if it's possible target these items within a loop, where `N` is the number of `divs`. In the first loop I want to target the first `div`, in the second loop the second `div`, etc...

```
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    $(".className")...
};
```

Also, it's possible to know the number of `divs` with the same class with jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$(...)` notation returns an array-like object, meaning you can refer to a specific element through its index:

```
$(".className")[i]...
```

However it's worth noting that jQuery has a couple of its own looping methods, including [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) which can probably be used instead of a native `for` loop in this case:

```
$(".className").each(function() {
    var current_element = $(this);
});
```

jQuery objects implement JavaScript's `length` property, so you can use this to count the number of matching elements:

```
var number_of_divs = $(".className").length;
```

---

To satisfy the requirements your question asks for:

```
var elems = $('.className'),
    N = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
    elems[i]...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.className').each(function(){
    // your logic
});
```

To know total no. of div with same class,

```
var totalDivs = $('.className').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can know the length

```
$('.className').length;
```

The size size();

```
$('.className').size(); // Deprecated since jQuery 1.8 though
```

Or just use each

```
$('.className').each(function(){  // code    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop you can use `.each()`

```
$(".className").each(function(){});
```

And to get the total number you just have to use the property `length`.

```
var numOfDiv = $(".className").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

U need each() function know.

```
   $(".className").each(function(Integer index, Element element){
.......
   });
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('.className'),function(index,value){
console.log(value);
})
console.log('LENGTH : '+$('.className').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

When running `$('.className')`, you are actually creating a list of all elements with that specific class, wrapped in a jQuery object. You could run `.each()` on this object to iterate all elements, like this:

```
$('.className').each(function (index, element) {
  // this refers to the current element here (not wrapped in a jquery object)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
var elems = $('.className');
N = elems.length; // this gives no. of divs
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    $(elems[i])...  // by using this you can point to each div with same class name
}
```

Comment: Your answer adds nothing to discussion.